# Query Cursor with App Engine (Java - JDO)

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo

I need to implement pagination in my result fetching so while looking around, I got a link to Query Cursors on the Google Developer site but the article explains the use of Query Cursors using the low-level API (I avoid this thing like the plague). Everything I saw on JDO uses `setRange(start, end)` which (if I'm right) is not so efficient as you still pay for the overhead involved in fetching and discarding results preceding the range.
How can I use Query Cursors in JDO on top of the App Engine Datastore?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From appengine docs:

```
Query q = pm.newQuery(Person.class);
q.setRange(0, 20);

List<Person> results = (List<Person>) q.execute();
// Use the first 20 results

Cursor cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(results);
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries

Then, to use the cursor (also in the documentation provided, which you should read):

```
String cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();
// Send cursor around as string


// Query q = the same query that produced the cursor;
Cursor cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
Map<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
q.setExtensions(extensionMap);
q.setRange(0, 20); //note, the same range; 
//the query should cover everything you expect to load.
q.execute();
```

Comment: PS - To use cursors, you have to request more than you want, and you choose when to end the query; either you get fewer results than one page, or you get more, and choose to end early (and send the cursor back as well to continue on the next query).  Use query chunk size to avoid requesting more than one full page. Also, beware that a request using a query that returns no results will send back the same cursor you used to build the query.  Null cursor = no results.  Same cursor = no new results.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how do I construct queries with start and end cursors (JDO)?

Comment: Updated answer to include example usage.  Note that you'll want to set the same range; the full query itself should be over the complete range you expect to cover; the cursor allows you to stop part way through, and continue again later.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think you only showed me how to continue from the last query (i.e use the cursor as a start cursor). But here is a use case in my app: the client has made query (to a rapidly update data (e.g tweets), now the app wants to fetch fresh contents only (i.e query from the beginning of the data to the point of the last cursor, which means using the cursor as an end cursor). I've seen this in the low-level GAE/J API but how do I do it in JDO?

Comment: It depends how you are sorting your data.  If you sort on time ASC, then new results will be past the end of your cursor.  So, query on time > userLatestKnownTime, range (0, 1000).  The value of userLatestKnownTime will be some fixed point near the fresh data on which to base the query.  Pull in the first page of data without a cursor, and store the highest known time.  Use that for your cursor query. If you hit the end of the range, just update the latestTime, and start a new cursor.